# how to add dynamically an specific div after each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I'm trying to add dynamically a `div` after click on a "reply" class, it is just repeat for my first `div`.

I want to add that div after each `div` but it is just works for the first one.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".repetable").hide();
  $(".reply").bind("click", function () {
    $(".repetable").hide();
    $(".repetable").slideDown("slow")
    $("#nazar").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <!--div 1-->
    <div class="comment1">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 1-->
    <div class="repetable">
        <form class="formnazar-user">
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--div 2-->
    <div class="comment1">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT2</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 2-->
    <div class="repetable">
        <form class="formnazar-user">
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you call jquery library? Where do you append `.reply`? Please, post your completed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem, after `.reply` click the both of the `.repetable` did the `slidedown()` animation.

So, you just need to do this only on the `.repetable` that come after the comment. So, you need to use the [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) function,

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".repetable").hide();
  $(".reply").bind("click", function () {
    // $(".repetable").hide(); - You don't need it
    // You want to do this only for the next div after the sepecific comment
    $(this).parents('.comment1').next().slideDown("slow");
    //$(".repetable").slideDown("slow")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <!--div 1-->
    <div class="comment1">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 1-->
    <div class="repetable">
        <form class="formnazar-user">
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--div 2-->
    <div class="comment1">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT2</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 2-->
    <div class="repetable">
        <form class="formnazar-user">
            <input type="text" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you select by the same class. All your "repetable" divs will be affected by your

```
$(".repetable").hide();
    $(".repetable").slideDown("slow")
```

To solve this, you can make the HTML to look more like this. Note the replay input is inside the comment where it actually belongs. (or you can use a different parent to group the comment div with the comment replay input)

```
<div class="main">
    <!--div 1-->
    <div class="comment">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
        <div class="repetable">
            <form class="formnazar-user">
                <input type="textbox" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 1-->


    <!--div 2-->
    <div class="comment">
        <p>YOUR COMMENT2</p>
        <div class="reply">
            reply
        </div>
        <div class="repetable">
            <form class="formnazar-user">
                <input type="textbox" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End div 2-->

</div>
```

After that, you can use a js event handler like this, to dynamically select the replay input related to the replay button that the user just clicked:

```
$(".repetable").hide();
          $(".reply").bind("click", function(e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            var targetRepeatable = target.parents('.comment').find('.repetable');
            targetRepeatable.hide();
            targetRepeatable.slideDown("slow")
            $("#nazar").slideUp("slow");
          });
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/hm1zxy5b/

Thanks